# How to call formflow by clicking a button in bot framework c#

Tags: c#, botframework

I am new in programming facebook bots. I'm using microsoft bot framework in c#.

I want to start a dialog or a formflow when user choose one choise from quick reply.

When i try to to this using this code i dont get nothing as responde...or i got error

[error photo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKsmo.jpg)
[image: Screenshot]

---

In my Rootdialog.cs im using  this code :

```
 private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        //if you choose start parking
        if (message.Text == Resources.RootDialog_Welcome_Start)
        {
            this.order = new Models.Order();

            var promptOptions = new PromptOptions<string>(
                "Please select the city where you want to park:",
                options: new[] { "a", "b", "c" },
                promptStyler: new ());

            PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.ResumeAfterSelection, promptOptions);

        }




private async Task ResumeAfterSelection(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var cityRange = await result;
            if (cityRange == "Brussels")
            {




context.Call(FormDialog.FromForm<Enquiry>(Enquiry.BuildEnquiryForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart), async (ctx, formResult) => ctx.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync));
                //var myform = new FormDialog<Enquiry>(new Enquiry(), Enquiry.BuildEnquiryForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);
```

Enquiry.cs is

```
[Serializable]
public class Enquiry : LuisDialog<StartParking>
{
    private Func<IForm<Enquiry>> buildEnquiryForm;



    public Enquiry(Func<IForm<Enquiry>> buildEnquiryForm)
    {
        this.buildEnquiryForm = buildEnquiryForm;
    }

    public Enquiry()
    {
    }

    [Prompt("What time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    [Prompt("Placenumber?")]
    public string PlaceNumber { get; set; }
    [Prompt("Platenumber?")]
    public string Platenumber { get; set; }



    public IEnumerable<EntityRecommendation> Entities { get; internal set; }



    public static IForm<Enquiry> BuildEnquiryForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<Enquiry>()

            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe `context.Call` needs an `IDialog`, so try using `Chain.From` to build one up from `FormDialog.FromForm`:

```
internal static IDialog<Enquiry> MakeRoot()
{
    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm<Enquiry>(Enquiry.BuildEnquiryForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart)); 
}
```

then call it using:

```
context.Call(MakeRoot, async (ctx, formResult) => ctx.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync));
```